# Perfomance impact of global state in a pure react state managed application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React Hooks for state management, a quick overview:

I am using the `useContext` hook to distribute the application state to the inner components. These contexts provide an object like: `{ state, dispatch }` which is returned from a `useReducer` hook.

```
const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer({...}, initialState);
return (
  <MyContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
     {children}
  </MyContext.Provider>
);
```

Then the state is accessible by inner components:

```
<MyContext>
  <SomeComponent/>
</MyContext>
```

As the application grows, there will be multiple contexts like this one, so I'm tempted to create another component called `Store`, and just put all the contexts there, wrapping my App:

Store.jsx:

```
export const Store = ({children}) => (
<SomeContext>
  <AnotherContext>
    {children}
  </AnotherContext>
</SomeContext>
)
```

App·jsx:

```
<Store>
  <App/>
</Store>
```

Now, the actual question is: **Can this approach cause unnecessary re-renders? And what impact it could have performance-wise in the long run?**

Comment: You can use the useMemo hook to avoid unnecessary re-renders

Comment: Nice, would you add an answer with some code and/or links so that I can have a better look at it? @muddassir

Comment: You can have a look at this https://dev.to/spukas/react-usememo-for-optimisation-5gna

Comment: Create a sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mendeleev-l2467 - This is just an example there can be a better approach